# How to set up MS Visual Studio to warn me about class instance comparison with operator ==?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, configuration, visual-studio-2015

Regular condition looks like this:

```
if (number == 5) ...
```

but if I am comparing class instances I need to use the `Equals` method. So let's say I have instances a, b of some class, then it would look like this:

```
if (a.Equals(b)) ...
```

What I need is to set up Visual Studio 2015 to warn/error me if I do this:

```
if (a == b)
```

In other words if I use equal operator for class instances.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You may found [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) helpful.

Comment: why would you do that, it is the same thing (for Objects I mean)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(VS.80).aspx read this

Comment: `if I am comparing class instances I need to use the Equals method` Why is that?  It's generally poor design for a class's `Equals` implementation to differ from it's `operator ==` implementation.  If it does you should really *fix that problem* instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard way is to create your custom rule like [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2010/03/26/how-to-write-custom-static-code-analysis-rules-and-integrate-them-into-visual-studio-2010.aspx) but it is a bit difficult.

The easy way is to use [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) and create a custom rule but it is a commercial tool.

Another thing is overloading `==` operator in every class so it throws an exception, but it only works if you are using your own classes and it is a bit tiresome.

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer ;).

Comment: No problem. I have been once facing the same thing, so now I did only quick research to see if something changed but with no luck. Now I am using my student licence on Reshaper so I guess this is my solution :)
But If you will decide to write such VS rule, please post it here. I think you will bring a great thing to this community :)

Comment: Why would you overload it to throw an exception instead of overloading it to just provide the exact semantics you want it to have?

Comment: Because I assumed you want to fight with habit - if you 'redirect' `==` to `Equals` you won't notice you 'made a mistake`. If your program crashes instead of not working properly, you will notice immediately :)

Comment: The idea of overloading the operator is completely the wrong way. You want the compiler to tell you that you made the mistake, not the runtime!

The best way to achieve something like this is with the new Roslyn analyzers or the good old FxCop rules.

Comment: @HugoQuintelaRibeiro, You are right... but I disagree. You see, there is a straightforward connection between compile warnings and runtime errors. We have modern languages with modern IDE with deep code analysis, so you can be advised to look after some methods invocation because, lets say, they will always raise an exception. In this particular case you might want to implement throwing exception, so some mechanizm will warn you about it as a compile warning. Isn't this what we wanted? It is far more worse solution but it's better than none :)